# PHP Payal update MySQL based on product bought

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I'm making a paid membership system. I have the login, registration, and all that down. I have got a payment, plans, and gateway table in MySQL. The gateway contains the email for Paypal, the plans has all the plans with prices and are ordered by ID. The payment is suppose to store all the payments made by the users. I was wondering about how I would go about having it automatically update MySQL based on which plan you bought. So if User 1 bought Plan A which had a 1 month expiry time, it would set a 1 month expiry time in the user table which has a column with 'expire'. The login will check if the user has expired. But I was wondering on how to update this column with the product bought. Will I have to register products on Paypal or can I send a certain ID and paypal will reconginze the product the user is trying to buy.

Thank you in advanced, I'm writing too much. Please comment for more details if you do need it. I will be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to handle this sort of thing is with [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, including automatically fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.